# Ошибка поиска по части текста ссылки

Tags: python, selenium

Почему для данной ссылки не работает этот код на python + selenium. Я получаю ошибку selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element.

```
<a href="f?p=503:41:2439973897953::NO::P41_GROUP_ID:6159" title="Просмотр журналов"><span class="TEXT_O">Журналы</span></a>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '6159').click()
```

Comment: Понимание синтаксиса URL-адреса f?p https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/understanding-legacy-url-syntax.html#GUID-ABC99726-E754-4AC1-8C87-8B684D2F8D42